# adding to a textfield in panel1 from a button in panel2

Tags: java, swing, action, panel

Ok so I have 2 jPanels.

one of them has a number of buttons that when pressed should add text to the the textfield that is in the second jPanel.

I am brand spanking new to swing with previously only having to write back end code and web based code so I am having difficulty seeing how you would accomplish this.

I only have buttons created in one panel and a textfield in another so i suspect code would be irrelevant.

Any articles that someone could point me to or examples are greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should start with basic swing tutorial.`jtextfieldof2ndpanel.settext("text");` will add text

Comment: this won't work on account that my buttons are within a panel so when i instantiate both panels i need a way of them interacting such that a button clicked in one panel will add text into the textfield in the other panel

Comment: `ActionListeners` adds in JButtons which handle click on each button. In this listeners(_one listener for all button or each listener for each button, nevermind_) appears logic and setting text to your JTextField.

Comment: @Ivan how would the actionlistener know to place the text in a textfield that is in a different panel from the actionlistener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make the `JTextField` an instance variable of the enclosing `JFrame` and make the two panels inner classes of it. By this, the two panels will have a reference to the same field which belongs to the outer class.

So, you will end up having something similar to:

```
public class Outer extends JFrame{
      private JTextField text = new JTextField();
      ...

      public Outer(){
        this.add(new Inner1(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(new Inner2(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      }

      class Inner1 extends JPanel{
        ...
         public Inner1(){
            this.add(text);
         }  
      }

      class Inner2 extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
             private JButton button = new JButton();

             public Inner2(){
                button.addActionListener(this);
             }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if (e.getSource() == button)
                text.setText("Hello StackOverFlow");
        } 
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So I had this problem ones,

So Lets say you have two JFrame `JFrame1 and JFrame2` 
In order to communicate with each other at runtime both has to have most recent initialized object of each individual frame.

Now lets say this is your first frame where is your textbox,

```
public class JFrame1 extends JFrame{

    JTextField jTextField= null;

    public JFrame1() throws HeadlessException {
        super("JFrame");
        setSize(200, 200);

        jTextField = new JTextField();
        add(jTextField);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void setValueToText(String value){
        jTextField.setText(value);
    }
}
```

Then This is second and where is your Button,

```
public class JFrame2 extends JFrame{

    JButton jButton= null;
    JFrame1 frame1=null;

    public JFrame2() throws HeadlessException {
        super("JFrame");

        frame1=new JFrame1();

        jButton = new JButton("Clieck Me");
        add(jButton);
        setVisible(true);
        jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                frame1.setValueToText("Hi");
            }
        });

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame2 jf= new JFrame2();
        jf.setSize(200, 200);
    }
}
```

Now Just run second class file and click one button which will set hi on your textbox which is in second frame.
So As you see answer lay's in Initialized second object in frame.

My execution is like,

1. Run JFrame2
2. Initialized JFrame1 in JFame2 const.

Comment: ahh sorry i forgot to add that panel1 and panel2 (not jFrame but jPanel) are within frame1 instead of panel2 being within panel1

Comment: @user1383163 And this changes the concept been present how?

Comment: Not the best example, but definitely one of the better conceptual solutions

Comment: @user1383163 Solution is going to same and now you have to use two JPanel instead of JFrame. But 1QQ those panels are inside same container or diff ?

Answer (score 0):

add your code to change the text in another panel, when a button clicked in the first panel.

```
mybutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

               //do your logic to change the text in another panel

            }
        });
```

Comment: yes but the event body cannot reference the textfield as it does not exist in frame1 but rather frame2 which it has no knowledge of